# SOAP "error fetching http headers": how do I do suspected solution of disabling keep-alive?

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, soap, keep-alive

I'm troubleshooting an existing webservice.  It previously worked just fine, but now SOAP-based requests to the postgreSQL database result in an "unknown error: Error Fetching http headers" error.

In looking up this problem, I come across the following tip:

> When you get errors like: "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception:
>   [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in"  after a few (time intensive)
>   SOAP-Calls, check your webserver-config.
>
> Sometimes the webservers "KeepAlive"-Setting tends to result in this
>   error. For SOAP-Environments I recommend you to disable KeepAlive.
>
> Hint: It might be tricky to create a dedicated vhost for your
>   SOAP-Gateways and disable keepalive just for this vhost because for
>   normal webpages Keepalive is a nice speed-boost.

I haven't been able to figure out exactly how you disable KeepAlive or where this parameter would be set.  I've tried `grep -i "keepalive" /usr/share/tomcat5/conf/*`, result negative.

Perhaps due to the variability of server environments this is a question for my sysadmin, but I do have root privileges.

Thanks for your help, stack!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Tomcat's server.xml file, set the maxKeepAliveRequests attribute to 1 on your HTTP connectors to effectively disable keep alive.

For more information:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm trying to figure out which connector this would go with.  PostgreSQL seems to connect through the postmaster process, which uses port 5432.  There isn't currently a connector to 5432.  Should I create a new connector?  I hesitate to do so without knowing more, since for months it was apparently connecting to the db just fine without one.